# Running multiple services on one Port 443 is possible?

Tags: windows-server-2008, firewall, ssl-certificate, https, wcf

I am new to network and firewall things,

In our 2008 R2 server i have configured WCF service on windows service with port 443 and later i found another windows service already using the same port 443(SstpSvc - Secure Socket Tunneling Protocol Service), but while configuring 443 for my url i did not get any error.

Note: our server is under firewall

is it a problem to have two services with same port 443.

please help me.

Thanks,

Pradeep

Answer (score 3):

> Running multiple services on one Port 443 is possible?

No.

> is it a problem to have two services with same port 443.

Yes.

This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320596/wcf-service-port

Comment: can you advice me if i disable SstpSvc - Secure Socket Tunneling Protocol Service will it create any problem

Comment: Looks like you can disable it if you're not using a VPN or other service that uses it. You could try disabling it and see if anything breaks.

Answer (score 1):

It is best to run it on different port. However if you have good reason not to there are protocol multiplexers available.
For port 443 there is
http://www.rutschle.net/tech/sslh.shtml

This service listens on port 443 (as only one process can listen at one port) and when it receives connection depending on first few bits sent by client determines the protocol and reroutes to other ports. For example you can have ssh and https both connectable trough port 443.
However services themselves run on different ports. *(as per definition only one process can open port with same number.)*

### Example of my configuration:

1. ssh listens on port 22
2. https web server listens on 444
3. sslh listens on 443 and depending on what client sends after establishing connection reroutes to 22 or 444

Comment: Don't make it too complicated to the OP since he seems to lack some basics.